# CSS Window resizing on Browsers height

Tags: css, position, positioning, css-position

what I try is to create a window, that has fixed width and is centered.
Should also have variable height, depending on the browsers-viewport-height with a top offset of 20px and a bottom offset of 20 px;

I don't want to use JQuery / JS for this it should be in plain css.

Here some code-snipped:

```
#viewport should be the the browsers height / width container
#window should be the resized window (centered in middle, filling up all height except of top 20px and bottom 20px
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ejRTU/87/

Someone has any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use position: absolute and set the top and bottom attributes to 10px; See this fiddle `jsfiddle.net/ejRTU/88/`

Comment: thx my hero ;D ^^ (will mark this as answer, but i'll have to wait 5 minutes)